# Drawing on web form programmatically

Tags: asp.net, web, drawing, curve, programmatically-created

Is there any ways to programmatically draw on web form? I have a task to draw a shape on web form based on value input by user. The shape is variety which include rectangle, octagen, and some curve shape. And I need to put a label line to mention how long is every side of the shape.

Comment: Could you please post your code whatever you have tried so far so as to correct it in a better way.

Comment: There's loads of ways, many of which depend on what technologies you're already using so: please read through [how to ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask) and update your post accordingly. Also remember that Stackoverflow is not a general help forum, and asking for tool recommendations without any sign that you've already done your own investigations first is officially [off topic here](/help/on-topic).